# How to determine resonance frequency of a piezoceramic element?

Tags: frequency, resonance, piezoelectric

Lets say we have a circular piezoelectric element with radius R and height H. We assume that the piezoelectric element has density $\rho$. How do you find the resonance frequency ? Is there a formula for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a piezoelectric crystal has not only one resonance frequency but many.
Therefore I guess you want only the lowest resonance frequency.

Common piezoelectric crystals are very flat cylinders ($H \ll R$)
with the electrodes attached to both circular faces.
For this case the physics is simple enough to calculate the resonance
without sophisticated math.
(Actually the calculation below works not only for flat cylinders,
but also for flat cuboids, or any other flat forms with a homogenous
height $H$ much smaller than its lateral size.)

The lowest resonance is such that there fits half a wavelength
$\lambda$ into the height $H$:
$$ H = \frac{\lambda}{2} $$

Wavelength $\lambda$ and frequency $f$ are connected
by the speed of sound $c_s$: $$ \lambda f = c_s $$

Hence, you get the frequency
$$ f = \frac{c_s}{2 H}. $$

For common piezo-materials you can look up their speeds of sound in
[The Free Dictionary - Piezoelectric Materials](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Piezoelectric+Materials).

Example:
Quartz has a speed of sound $c_s = 5.47 \cdot 10^3\ \text{m/s}$.
For a flat cylindrical quartz slab with height $H = 1\ \text{mm}$
you get a frequency
$$f = \frac{c_s}{2 H}
 = \frac{5.47 \cdot 10^3\ \text{m/s}}{2\cdot 1\ \text{mm}}
 = 2.73\ \text{MHz}$$

Answer (score 0):

I want to design a PZT transducer with 3kw o acoustic power and in 20khz resonance, please help me and show a suitable content about this matter.
With best regards
S.Abbasi